# What is the cardinality of $O(f(x))$?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, cardinals

I was wondering what the cardinality of

$$O(f(x))=\left\{g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\left|\lim_{x\to\infty}\sup\frac{|g(x)|}{f(x)}<\infty
\right.\right\}$$
is.

I know that if $g(x)=cf(x)$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$ then $g(x)\in O(f(x))$, hence $\{c\in\mathbb R|cf(x)\}\subset O(f(x))$. As $|\mathbb R|=\beth_1$, this implies $|\{c\in\mathbb R|cf(x)\}|=\beth_1$. At the same time, $O(f(x))\subset\{g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\}$ and $|\{g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\}|=\beth_2$.

The implication is that

$$\beth_1\leq|O(f(x))|\leq\beth_2$$

However, I'm not sure whether $|O(f(x))|=\beth_1$ or $|O(f(x))|=\beth_2$. Could anybody figure out what the cardinality of $O(f(x))$ is?

Comment: I think it should be emphasized, that $f \ne 0$. Also $g(x)=cf(x)$ seems is typo in definition: it should be $g(x)\leqslant cf(x)$

Comment: Good point with the first, however the $g(x)=cf(x)$ is intentional (the set of $g$ such that $g(x)=cf(x)$ is a subset of $O(f(x))$ so I used the cardinality of that as a lower bound of the cardinality of $O(f(x))$, hence $\beth_1\leq|O(f(x))|$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any subset $A\subset [0,1]$ and define $f_A(x):=\chi_A(x)+f(x)\chi_{[0,1]^c}(x)$.

Since $A\subset[0,1]$, it is clear taht $f_A\in O(f(x))$ and $|\{f_A:\, A\subset [0,1]\}=|\cal P[0,1]|=\beth_2$

---

For the sake of completenes $$\chi_A(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in A\\0&x\notin A\end{cases}$$

Comment: What is $\chi_A(x)$? What about $c$?

Comment: The characteristic function of $A$.

Comment: I'm guessing $\chi_{A^c}(x)$ returns $0$ when $x\in A$ and $1$ when $x\notin A$?

Comment: Yes, but i have edited the answer to be a liitle bit more clear:

Comment: The hey is to put in $[0,1]$ whatever you want. MOREOVER, if $f$ is continuous, you can take inside $[0,1]$ ANY continuous functions $g$ with $g(0)=f(0)$ and $g(1)=f(1)$.